# How can i create Dynamic xpath using live data from user input and put in my xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to use some live input from user and put those input in my xpath and find the element.

For Example:-

1 . I want to search some courses in a page

2 . After Enter the text in search box.

3 . Dropdown show the courses and I want to select the courses from Dropdown

4 . But In DOM class Name is same for all courses and id is different

5 . But using ID unable to search the Element and i already used condition time also.

screenshot:-http://prntscr.com/o09nq5

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you:

`public IWebElement GetUserNameElement(string usrName, IWebDriver driver)
    {
        return driver.FindElementByXPath(($"//div[@id='{usrName}']"));
    }`

This is from an old project of mine written in C#. I had the same problem as you here where I had to pull an object base on what the user name was. Now you just need to call this and pass the input and driver to it.